# Finding area of successive triangles

Tags: geometry

> Let the lines $L_1\equiv\sqrt{3}\ x-y +(2-\sqrt{3})=0$ and $L_2\equiv\sqrt{3}\ x+y -(2+\sqrt{3})=0$ intersect at $A$. Let $B_1$ be a point on $L_1$. From $B_1$, draw a line perpendicular to $L_1$ meeting the line $L_2$ at $C_1$. From $C_1$, draw a line perpendicular to $L_2$ meeting the line $L_1$ at $B_2$. Continue in this way obtaining points $C_2$, $B_3$, $C_3$ and so on. If area of triangle $AB_1C_1=1$ and $\text{area}(\Delta AB_2C_2) +\text{area}(\Delta AB_3C_3) +\text{area}(\Delta AB_4C_4) =T$, then $|T-4360|={}$_________________.

In this question I tried using co-ordinate plane.
For the first triangle I could get $B_1$ but the coordinates are 
very clumsy. 
Is there some geometrical method?

Comment: Hint: all the triangles $AB_iC_i$ are similar, and their areas follow a geometric progression. I think working with angles and lengths is easier than coordinates, but I haven't actually tried.

Comment: But for finding the ratio wont we require use of coordinate geometry.

Comment: Maybe. As I said, I haven't tried.

Comment: how do they follow gp?

Comment: Because the figures $AB_iC_iB_{i+1}C_{i+1}$ are all similar. So the ratio $\frac{|AB_{i+1}C_{i+1}|}{|AB_iC_i|}$ of areas must be constant.

Comment: yes thanks . got ratio as 16.

Comment: it is a good question. i dont found the logic of downvoting

Comment: The downvote fairy does work in mysterious ways. Some times I know what it's thinking and some times not at all.